# nodejs shopify api 404 not found but all other api requests works

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I use shopify node api and make some api calls.

All works, I use access scopes and get some products and it works fine. But when I want to get the collections I get this:

404 Bad request

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
    at settle (C:\express_inngest\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:19:12)
    at BrotliDecompress.handleStreamEnd (C:\express_inngest\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:572:11)
    at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at BrotliDecompress.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: 'http',
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: null },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'shpat_xxxxxxxxxx32221xx',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.5.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
```

My Question is now why other apis works and this not ? I copied the URL from the docs so there is no typo.

Here is my ohter code:

```
export const buildGetCollectionUrl = (shop: any) => `https://${shop}/admin/api/2023-04/collection_listings.json`;

export const fetchCollection = async (shop: any, accessToken: any) => await axios(buildGetCollectionUrl(shop), {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken
  }
});

const shopify = shopifyApi({
  apiKey: 'xxxx',
  apiSecretKey: 'xxxx',
  scopes: ['read_products', 'write_products', 'read_orders', 'write_orders', 'read_product_listings', 'write_product_listings', 'unauthenticated_read_product_listings'],
  hostName: '93c5-2a02-908-4b74-122s-e9a8-dd08-43ef-4725.ngrok-free.app/',
  apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  isEmbeddedApp: true
});


app.get('/auth/callback', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    // The library will automatically redirect the user
    const callback = await shopify.auth.callback({
      rawRequest: req,
      rawResponse: res,
    });

    const response = await shopify.webhooks.register({
      session: callback.session,
    });

    const { data: collections } = await fetchCollection(callback.session.shop, callback.session.accessToken);
    console.log(collections);
    return res.send('x');
....
```

It goes to the auth0 process and all works I also get the access token so in other api urls it works but not this for collection. Can anyone explain me why it is not working when I want to get the collections ?